# Javascript socket io hide ip adres to connect

Tags: javascript, socket.io, cloudflare

I use cloudflare, but in my code is my ip address, its look like:

```
 var socket1 = io.connect('http://188.33.35.9:3002');
```

Is any possible to hide it?

Comment: Still visible after minifying JavaScript?

Comment: yes, yes, yes, yes

Comment: Do you realize that any moderate techy can see what IP address that any web page connects to.  It's fairly trivial once you know how and the info comes from the actual connection, not from the web page so there's no way to hide that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without changes to your application. CloudFlare does not proxy traffic on nonstandard HTTP ports, such as 3000.

For details, see CloudFlare's FAQ "[Which ports will CloudFlare work with?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-CloudFlare-work-with-)".

If you can change your application to use a supported port, use the CloudFlare domain name for your application in place of the IP address.

Comment: What you mean by "CloudFlare domain name" ? you mean cloudflare.com ?

Comment: The name of the domain that's being hosted with Cloudflare.